# Heroku and writing oauth credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

(This is NOT ABOUT OAUTH but about storing a key and a value)

I wrote a simple app that queries my twitter account and then process the tweets from my timeline.

I am able to obtain my oauth token and secret but as it turns out I can't really store them on the filesystem on heroku for some unknown reason.

basically I have the following code:

```
  task :heroku => :environment do 
    desc "manually store the keys for heroku in oauth_path"
    File.open(oauth_path, 'w') do |f| 
      f.puts ENV['token']
      f.puts ENV['secret']
    end

    puts "Token and Secrent written to #{oauth_path}"
  end
```

this works on local filesystem but not on heroku.

I have a task which then opens oauth_path and then run the twitter app with those token and secret.

I have set up cron on heroku to execute `rake myapp:pull`

Any ideas how I can store the key value and then write my app as `rake myapp:pull` ??

Comment: I don't think you can write files on Heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem  You need to use a database of some sorts or other remote storage.

Comment: oh I see. All I need is to store oauth-token and oauth-secret, both of which might change over time. Any simple solutions you can think of?

Comment: It would be better to store them in the database. (connecting to external storage would be an overkill, such as S3...)

Comment: @PeterWong Any simple key value store?

Comment: Heroku provides serval databases including **redis to go**, which is a key value store. If your currently database design is not that complex, creating a User (or whatever you want) model for the default database should be enough and the most easy. If there is only 1 user, then just get `User.first`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set up an enviroment varible on heroku to store this information, it should not be stored inside a database since that could be potentially less secure.

You set keys like this:

```
$ cd myapp
$ heroku config:add S3_KEY=8N029N81 S3_SECRET=9s83109d3+583493190
Adding config vars:
  S3_KEY    => 8N029N81
  S3_SECRET => 9s83109d3+583493190
Restarting app...done.
```

And access them like this:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']
)
```

See the [documentation for more info](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Comment: great! Exactly what I need. How can I test this in development though.